# Post Image File from App Inventor to Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, app-inventor

I have posted image file from App Inventor to Google Apps Script web app.

Attached App inventor Blocks for Image Upload
 
[App Inventor Blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTbEq.png)
[image]

Below is Code for Google App Script WebApp for Processing Post request, so that Image in post body can be saved to google drive

```
function doPost(eventInfo) {

  MyLog("doPost", "eventInfo", eventInfo.parameters);

if(eventInfo.parameter.type === 'test') {

var destination_id = "0B63z7K35zZN9ZzhEc1NaQV9XaDA";
var img = eventInfo.postData.contents;
var file = Utilities.newBlob(img);
var contentType = "image/jpeg";

MyLog("Test", "check", contentType);

var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(destination_id);
var driveFile = destination.createFile("Test",file,"image/jpeg"); 
var fileName = driveFile.getName();
MyLog("doPost", "check", fileName);
 }
```

How to process the postData.contents to save the image file to Google Drive

Comment: @Cooper : e.parameter.type is given name eventInfo.parameter.type, Ref - function doPost(eventInfo) instead of function doPost(e)

Comment: The  parameter.type is nothing but key value pair sent in url string, check the app inventor blocks,